# Nexus repository manager, disable summary view on package

Tags: nexus, nexus3

Is there a way to disable the Summary view for anonymous users when browsing packages?

I want to hide this section:
[image: section]

Is there a way to achieve this? The repository-read permission allows this section to be displayed.

Comment: Pretty sure this cannot be done, the permission scheme isn't that granular.  Suggest filing an improvement request on https://issues.sonatype.org and they can probably tell you on review if I'm wrong.

Comment: May I ask which of the fields would like to be hidden?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do that would be to disable the `nx-repository-view-*-browse` for a given repository. Effectively this would hide the component from the UI, while it would still be available to access via a direct link (e.g., by maven client). In other words, there is no way to keep a component listed in the UI and accessible, but to hide it's metadata.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed comment, but the privilege 'nx-repository-view-*-browse' hides the whole page, it is only accessible by direct link. I have seen nexus sites where only this section is hidden; but still that the page is accessible by clicking through the homepage.